# Qt 5.2.1 fails to build on mac OSX 10.8.5

Tags: c++, macos, qt, build, qt5

I downloaded Qt 5.2.1 (the .tar.gz) on my Macbook running OS X 10.8.5 with xcode 5.0.2, unzipped, and ran this configure:

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -debug-and-release -developer-build -no-c++11 -opensource -plugin-sql-sqlite -qtlibinfix _fmosoft -nomake tests -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -no-compile-examples
```

I have a few patches to add to Qt5.2.1, so I can't just install the binaries.  But I thought I'd first try to build without any patches, just using the unzipped code with my configuration options.  Configure succeeds, then I run

```
make
```

That runs for about 5 minutes, then gives me this error:

```
../corelib/global/qt_pch.h:58:10: error: 'qglobal.h' file not found with
      <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <qglobal.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
         "qglobal.h"
../corelib/global/qt_pch.h:64:10: fatal error: 'qcoreapplication.h' file not
      found
#include <qcoreapplication.h>
         ^
2 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [.pch/debug/QtNetwork_fmosoft_debug/c++.pch] Error 1
make[3]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-network-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I build Qt5.2.1 on my Macbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix is the installation prefix, it makes no sense for it to point to the `qtbase` folder in the build directory. Build directory is where you must invoke configure.

The following worked for me (dumped from `.bash_history` from an actual build on OS X 10.9):

```
mkdir $HOME/Qt/build-5.2.1
cd $HOME/Qt/build-5.2.1
~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/Src/configure -prefix "$HOME/Qt/5.2.1" -debug-and-release \
  -no-pkg-config -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake \
  -nomake examples
make -j2
make install
```

After `make install`, you get it installed to `$HOME/Qt/5.2.1`. That's what the prefix is.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying a non-prefix build, and that's what I found in Qt's documentation to put for -prefix (I forget where I saw it).  To see if it made a difference, I tried a normal prefix build as you suggested, but I got the same error as my original question.  Any more ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @DavidBurson It's probably an OS X 10.8-specific bug. You may wish to report it.

Comment: it appears to be a bug with -qtlibinfix.  By eliminating that flag I got past it.  Still fails with another error though:  /Users/david/dev/qt521source/qtbase/examples/widgets/mac/qmacnativewidget/main.mm:44:10: fatal error: 
      'QApplication' file not found
#include <QApplication>

Comment: @DavidBurson The error you give is in the examples. `-no-compile-examples` seems to be a no-op, use `-nomake examples` instead.

Comment: @DavidBurson I think part of your problem is adding a lot of custom options without succeeding with the defaults first. There's really no good reason for `-qtlibinfix` for example, since you're not installing Qt globally anyway, and you won't ever be (unless you work for Apple and they intend to ship Qt as part of OS X). It's sort-of useless. You may wish to check if there are any tests for it in the test suite: my hunch is that there are none, thus the buildbots never exercise it.

Comment: thanks!  You're right, I removed -qtlibinfix and -no-compile-examples and it has been building for several hours with this:  ./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -debug-and-release -developer-build -no-c++11 -opensource -plugin-sql-sqlite -nomake tests -confirm-license